# Send image inside mail body php script

Tags: php, email, sendmail, html-email

I want to show images in the body of the mail in php mail script

```
$formcontent=" Name: $name \n Picture: (I want to show the pic here)";
$recipient = "myemail@domain.com";
$subject = "Contact us";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
?>
```

I tried the following codes but it doesn't work, it shows the words as it is

```
$formcontent="<img src='http://anydomain.com/pic.jpg'>";  
$formcontent="<html><body><img src='http://images2.alphacoders.com/444/444259.jpg'></body></html>";
```

Comment: **A:** Consult http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and use `Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1` in your headers. It's all in there. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

tried the following codes .

```
$formcontent= "<img src=//anydomain.com/pic.jpg'>";

$formcontent= "<html><body><img src='//images2.alphacoders.com/444/444259.jpg'>

</body></html>";
```

Comment: Can you please explain the reason?